Homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{ Z/(p)}$
I'm trying to construct a non-zero ring homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{ Z/(p)}$. The question is for what $p$ is it possible. I managed with one direction:
$f(1) = f(-i^2)=-(f(i))^2 \equiv 1 \mod p \implies (f(i))^2 \equiv -1 \mod p \implies p = 4k+1$ 
Is it a sufficient condition for existence of a homomorphism? I am stuck here. Maybe I should somehow use the fact that $p = a^2+b^2, \ a, b \in \mathbb{Z}/ \{0\} $ or $p = (a + bi)(a - bi)?$ Give me a hint please.

Hint: $\mathbb{Z}[i] = \mathbb{Z}[X] / (X^2 + 1)$. Use the universal properties of polynomial and quotient rings.

OK, @Ben, but OP may not be familiar with the concept, "universal properties".

@GerryMyerson I'm sure that in case they don't they're perfectly capable of telling me/us so directly in response to my comment themselves. No need to guess.

OK, @Ben. mathemaniac, do you know what Ben means by "universal properties"?

Yes, it is possible whenever $p\equiv_4 1$, because then there are integers $a,b$ such that $p=a^2+b^2$. Also, as you rightly say, this implies that there is an element like $i$ in $\Bbb Z/(p)$, as
$$a^2+b^2\equiv_p 0\\\Rightarrow (ab^{-1})^2\equiv_p -1$$
We have the isomorphisms:

If $p=a^2+b^2$ then $$\Bbb Z[i]/(a+bi)\cong\Bbb Z/(p)$$


 Proof: Let $$\phi:\Bbb Z\rightarrow\Bbb Z[i]/(a+bi)$$ be defined by the canonical map $\phi(z)=z+(a+bi)\Bbb Z[i]$. To show that the map is surjective, we have that (since $a,b$ share no common factor) there exists $r,s\in\Bbb Z$ such that $$ar+bs=1$$ Consider then $(a+bi)(s+ri)=as-br+i$. Therefore for any $x+yi\in\Bbb Z[i]/(a+bi)$ we have that $\phi(x-(as-br)y)=x+yi$. We will show that $\ker(\phi)=(a^2+b^2)$. It is clear that $\phi(a^2+b^2)=0$, so suppose $\phi(n)=0$. Then $a+bi\mid n$, so $n=\alpha\cdot (a+bi)$. Taking complex conjugate we get $n=\bar{\alpha}\cdot (a-bi)$. So $(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2\mid n$, that is, $n\in (a^2+b^2)$. This relies on the fact that $a+bi,a-bi$ share no common factor, which is the case when $p\neq 2$. We therefore have $$\Bbb Z[i]/(a+bi)\cong\Bbb Z/(a^2+b^2)=\Bbb Z/(p)$$

In effect, since there is a map $$\Bbb Z[i]\rightarrow \Bbb Z[i]/(a+bi)$$ there is also a map $$\Bbb Z[i]\rightarrow \Bbb Z/(p)$$

You could also use the fact that $(p-1)!\equiv -1 \mod p$. If $p=4n+1$ then $(p-1)!=(2n)!(2n+1)...(4n)=(2n)!(p-2n)...(p-1)$, thus $-1\equiv(p-1)!\equiv (2n)!(2n)!(-1)^{2n}\equiv (2n)!^2\mod p$. Thus, $\mathbb{Z}[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $x\mapsto (2n)!$, induces a ring-homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[i]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.
